# Netbeans default browser doesn't start in Netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, browser, netbeans, ide

Scenario:

OS: Linux Debian 11
Kernel: 5.1.21
Browser: Mozilla Firefox 102.8.0esr
IDE: Netbeans 16
JDK: JAVA SE 19
Tomcat 10 (configured in netbeans)

In this scenario servlets run fine on tomcat writing URL on address bar. Trying to open the same URL with Browser in Netbeans fails because Browser doesn't come-up.

I perform following steps:

1. Single click on left button upon tomcat icon, then a Drop list come down with my Servlets
2. Right click Button on a Servlet (or tomcat main page), a second drop-list come down
3. Selecting "open in a Browser"
4. Browser doesn't start
5. Message info come-uo "Browser cannot Run): This message appears below in IDE netbeans and after few second vanished

I have also tried to compile index.html and as usual browser is expected to run, but in my case no! compiling process return no message error.

Looking for IDE Browser Configuration (TOOL>OPTION>GENERAL>EDIT) give me this set-up:
[External Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm1Tk.png)

Others browsers showed in the image above doesn't work. More-over next image shows IDE DEFAULT BROWSER without configuration. I tried to edit blank field but data were not saved after OK button click:
[IDE DEFAULT BROWSER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uEoH.png)
I tried to edit blank field but data were not saved after OK button click. I have to admit that this last trouble is my fault because I blanked them and now re-edit it again is impossible.

Comment: [1] On your final point (_"I tried to edit blank field..."_) my experience is that if you enter invalid values in the **Web Browsers Manager** screen (e.g. Specify an invalid path in the _Process_ field) and click **OK** then NetBeans will accept your invalid data without complaint, but if when you reopen that **Web Browsers Manager** screen you'll see that the invalid changes were discarded, and the previous values were preserved. [2] I can't reproduce your problem, though I am on Windows, not Linux...

Comment: ... [3] I have _Embedded WebKit Browser_ as one of my browser options, but you don't. Perhaps there is an installation or environment issue? [4] Check that there are no relevant errors or messages in the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**).

Comment: May be I get a relevant message on IDE Netbeans start-up:                                WARNING: package com.apple.eio not in java.desktop
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager (file:/usr/lib/apache-netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release

Comment: I reply to "skorisa": In Netbeans you get a entry "Default IDE Browser" after installation; I didn't set it by myself, I found it alredy configured. You also find in configuration another entry called "Argument". I erased these two values for mistake and if I try to re-edit those I click Ok button but when I re-open same window value entered by me before aren't there. Today I lhave lost the original data. and more important: "value entries stay blank.

Comment: OK. My environment is Win10/NB16/Java 20(Early access)/Tomcat 10.1.5, and I can't see/replicate any of your issues. I don't get your _"System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager..."_ message, but someone else who raised a [bug report with NetBeans](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5146) was getting that error. Rather than trying to further diagnose your individual issues, I think it might be easier just to reinstall NetBeans 16, using the most recent _officially supported_ version of Java (i.e. JDK 17, not JDK 19) if that is possible for you.

Comment: Also, FYI, to direct a comment to another user, just include their user ID, prefixed with an @ symbol, so to send me a comment include "@skomisa".

Comment: Downgrade IDE  Netbeans to 12.6 solve this issue. Incredible, but Default IDE Browser configuration shows every field blanks!

Comment: Interesting, and strange.  I can't replicate your problem on Windows, but since you and the bug report I linked to (which reported that _"System::setSecurityManager..."_ message) are both running Debian, perhaps it is related to the O/S? Anyway, since you have found a workaround, please consider posting an answer to your own question, and accepting it. That is more helpful to the community than having the resolution buried in the comments. Also consider [posting a bug report on this issue with NetBeans](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues) because as things stand you are stuck on 12.6.

Comment: @skomisa Ok, I post a solution, but I'am a newbie, review it please and tell me if it good or not.

Comment: @skomisa I have notice a mistake right now on my question. My Debian distribution is 10, not 11. Sorry, could you solvi this mistake in some way?

Comment: Regarding the Debian distribution, you can edit and update your question yourself. Just click "Edit" at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This problem currently does not have a definitive solution. Maybe it's related to OS Debian 10. I solved this issue with a downgrade of Netbeans IDE (12.6 version, may be a downgrade to 13 is better). My problem is even linked to Ubuntu Studio with KDE on Github at this link: [bug report with NetBeans](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5146).

In my case I also have GNOME 3 installed including many graphic tools. Furthermore, Ubuntu Studio is a Distro for graphics.  Maybe that is just a coincidence and nothing more but that could be it.

Answer (score 0):

Goto [Tools]-[Options]
Most likely, the [Default System Browser] is not setup in the app correctly, so pick an installed browser, click [Apply] & check a link.

[image]